# How do I use Rspec shared_examples across different files?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I want to reuse this `shared_examples` block across different spec files. I want to extract it into a separate file, and pass in the object so it's not always user. Both things I tried failed, is it possible?

```
describe User  do
  before  { @user = build_stubbed(:user) }
  subject { @user }

  shared_examples 'a required value' do |key| # trivial example, I know
    it "can't be nil" do
      @user.send("#{key}=", nil)
      @user.should_not be_valid
    end
  end

  describe 'name'
    it_behaves_like 'a required value', :name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `require` the other file. `shared_examples` work at the top level, so once defined they are always available; so be careful of naming conflicts.

A lot of RSpec users will put the shared example in `spec/support/shared_examples/FILENAME.rb`. Then in `spec/spec_helper.rb` have:

```
Dir["./spec/support/**/*.rb"].sort.each {|f| require f}
```

Or on Rails projects

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

That is listed in the ['CONVENTIONS'](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-core/example-groups/shared-examples/) section of the shared example docs.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I pass in the object? I tried this: `shared_examples 'a required value' do |object, key|` and then `it_behaves_like 'a required value', @user, :name` This produces an `undefined method name= on nilClass`. The object is not being passed in properly to the `shared_examples` block.

Comment: Never mind. I can use `subject`. I had two shared examples defined in two different locations.